# how can I read returned object from jQuery $.get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I was wondering how to extract data from a returned object via jQuery's $.get() method. IE:

```
function dynamicData(file){
    var wantedData;
    var getObj = $.get(file);
    wantedData = getObj.complete(function(data){return data;});
    return wantedData;
}
$(window).load(function(){
     var newData = dynamicData('somefile');
     alert(newData);
});
```

I don't want to just stick the data to some DOM as soon as it's gotten the new data.

I get an object alerted, but how do I get data inside of it? I have no idea how the object structure is at this point since newData is an object, but newData[0] is null. Is this by chance some sort of mapped object with key:value pairs? or are we not allowed to do it this way?

Comment: Use webkit's devtools or firebug or whatever to check for the object's structure! :D

Comment: Use Javascript console and instead of alert use console.log(newdata) so you can check its structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $.get() is asynchronous, you're calling your alert before the get returns any data.

A better approach would be:

```
function dynamicData(file,callback){
  $.get(file,function(data){
    callback(data);
  });
}

$(window).load(function(){
  dynamicData('somefile', alert);
});
```

which will alert(data) when it becomes available.

Answer (score 7):

You can't return from an Ajax call. It's Asynchronous.

Do whatever you want to do with the data in the success callback.

See [the manual for get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), which has examples.

Comment: Been there before i came here, but reason i was here because i didn't quite understand it there. I don't know much about the root of ajax at all. Especially those XMLHTTPRequest and all those ajax terms ;)

Answer (score 3):

$.get requires a callback function that will receive the data as soon as it is done loading. It will not directly return the data to the calling function!

Please refer to the [jQuery.get documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) for more information.